# Creating a list of enclosed items that mix figures and pdfs

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, tocloft

I need to list in a document enclosed items that are comprised of pdf's and images, in a certain order. The way I have approached this, is to use floats with option H[ere] for the images, and `includepdf` for the pdfs, and `newlistof` to list the items. In any case, I'm unable to get the page numbers right. Other imperfections mentioned in the code. Also, someone may know of a better approach altogether.

PS: Foo.pdf is a one page pdf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{keyfloat}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\listenclosedname}{List of enclosed items}
\newlistof[chapter]{enclosed}{encl}{\listenclosedname}

\NewDocumentCommand{\enclosedlabel}
{}
{
  %\protect something? TODO
  E{\small NCL.} \theenclosed.
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\addenclosed}
{m}
{
  \stepcounter{enclosed}
  \addcontentsline{encl}{enclosed}
  {
    %TODO: Replace
    E{\small NCL.} \theenclosed.
    % with:
    % % \enclosedlabel
    #1
  }
}

\begin{document}

\listofenclosed % BUG: Foo's page = 1 instead of 2.

\addenclosed{Baz}

\keyfigbox[H]{
  cstar={
    % enclosedlabel % TODO
  } 
}{\LARGE Baz}

\addenclosed{Foo}
\includepdf{Foo.pdf}

\addenclosed{Bar}

\keyfigbox[H]{
  cstar={}
}{\LARGE Bar}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: [Crosspost](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=31774&sid=9d8c344dff3da41668ecc21c2702535b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `\includepdf` starts a new page and fills it.  If you put `\addenclosed` in front, it will be on the preceding page.  If you put it after, it will be on the next page.  You can, however, use `\afterpage` to put it on the correct page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{keyfloat}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\newcommand{\listenclosedname}{List of enclosed items}
\newlistof[chapter]{enclosed}{encl}{\listenclosedname}

\NewDocumentCommand{\enclosedlabel}
{}
{
  %\protect something? TODO
  E{\small NCL.} \theenclosed.
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\addenclosed}
{m}
{
  \stepcounter{enclosed}
  \addcontentsline{encl}{enclosed}
  {
    %TODO: Replace
    E{\small NCL.} \theenclosed.
    % with:
    % % \enclosedlabel
    #1
  }
}

\begin{document}

\listofenclosed % BUG: Foo's page = 1 instead of 2.

\addenclosed{Baz}

\keyfigbox[H]{
  cstar={
    % enclosedlabel % TODO
  } 
}{\LARGE Baz}

\afterpage{\addenclosed{Foo}}
\includepdf{twopages}


\addenclosed{Bar}

\keyfigbox[H]{
  cstar={}
}{\LARGE Bar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, y doesn’t `enclosedlabel` work? I would like to label the included pdf’s with a watermark using the pkg by the same name. For that I need the cmd to get the page number of a given enclosed item. What is it?

Comment: `autopageref`, I guess.

Comment: If you use \refstepcounter and \label, you print the page number using \pageref.  See also \getpagerefnumber from refcount.