# babel conflicts with, I think, refcount

Tags: babel, refcount

The following code is continued from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448058/creating-a-list-of-enclosed-items-that-mix-figures-and-pdfs/448096?noredirect=1#comment1126188_448096) and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448717/using-xwatermark-with-pageref/448722?noredirect=1#comment1132310_448722). The following code compiles ok without `babel` but not with it. See the console output below. Is there a way resolve this issue?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[french]{babel} % no error if uncommented
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xwatermark} % ruled out

\newlistof{encl}{encl}{List of enclosed items}

\NewDocumentCommand
{\addencl}
{ m }
{
  \refstepcounter{encl}
  \addcontentsline{encl}{encl}{\theencl. #1}
}

\NewDocumentCommand
{\getencl}
{ m }
{
  E{\small NCL} \# \getrefnumber{#1}
}

\begin{document}
\newwatermark*[page=\getpagerefnumber{encl:bar}]{Bar}
\newwatermark*[page=\getpagerefnumber{encl:foo}]{Foo}

\listofencl

%\verb|\getrefnumber{encl:foo}|:\getrefnumber{encl:foo}
%\verb|\getpagerefnumber{encl:foo}|:\getpagerefnumber{encl:foo}

\getencl{encl:bar}~is~on~page~\getpagerefnumber{encl:bar}

\getencl{encl:foo}~is~on~page~\getpagerefnumber{encl:foo}

\newpage

%\refstepcounter{encl}
\addencl{Bar}\label{encl:bar}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}

\newpage

\addencl{Foo}\label{encl:foo}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}

%\newwatermark*{}


\end{document}
```

Console output:

> ERROR: Missing \endcsname inserted.
>
> --- TeX said ---  
>                      \unskip  l.36 \getencl{encl:bar}
>                          ~is~on~page~\getpagerefnumber{encl:bar}
>   --- HELP --- From the .log file...
>
> The control sequence marked  should not appear
>   between \csname and \endcsname.

Answer (score 4):

When `babel-french` is active, the colon has a special meaning: “remove a possible space, add a nonbreaking space and print the colon”.

Indeed, you get

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \unskip
```

LaTeX makes provision so that `\ref` or `\pageref` take care of `babel` shorthands such as `:`, `?` and `!` for French and `"` for German. This cannot be done with `\getrefnumber` or `\getpagerefnumber`, because the protection needs *assignments*, in this case setting a switch so that the colon shorthand, for instance, produces a standard colon.

The `refcount` commands want and *need* to be fully expandable and so no assignment can take place during their job: expandability is the feature for which `refcount` was born.

In general, I recommend avoiding `babel` shorthands in labels.

For your specific problem, where you use no macros in the argument to `\get(page)refnumber`, you can use `\detokenize`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel} % no error if uncommented
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xwatermark} % ruled out

\newlistof{encl}{encl}{List of enclosed items}

\NewDocumentCommand{\addencl}{ m }
 {%
  \refstepcounter{encl}%
  \addcontentsline{encl}{encl}{\theencl. #1}%
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\getencl}{ m }
 {%
  E{\small NCL} \# \getrefnumber{\detokenize{#1}}%
 }

\newcommand{\bgetpagerefnumber}[1]{\getpagerefnumber{\detokenize{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\newwatermark*[page=\bgetpagerefnumber{encl:bar}]{Bar}
\newwatermark*[page=\bgetpagerefnumber{encl:foo}]{Foo}

\listofencl

\getencl{encl:bar}~is~on~page~\bgetpagerefnumber{encl:bar}

\getencl{encl:foo}~is~on~page~\bgetpagerefnumber{encl:foo}

\newpage

%\refstepcounter{encl}
\addencl{Bar}\label{encl:bar}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}

\newpage

\addencl{Foo}\label{encl:foo}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}

%\newwatermark*{}


\end{document}
```

But it's much simpler using `encl-foo`.

Answer (score 3):

It will work if you use `\string:` in place of `:` at a number of locations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[french]{babel} % no error if uncommented
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xwatermark} % ruled out

\newlistof{encl}{encl}{List of enclosed items}

\NewDocumentCommand
{\addencl}
{ m }
{
  \refstepcounter{encl}
  \addcontentsline{encl}{encl}{\theencl. #1}
}

\NewDocumentCommand
{\getencl}
{ m }
{
  E{\small NCL} \# \getrefnumber{#1}
}

\begin{document}
\newwatermark*[page=\getpagerefnumber{encl\string:bar}]{Bar}
\newwatermark*[page=\getpagerefnumber{encl\string:foo}]{Foo}

\listofencl

%\verb|\getrefnumber{encl:foo}|:\getrefnumber{encl:foo}
%\verb|\getpagerefnumber{encl:foo}|:\getpagerefnumber{encl:foo}

\getencl{encl\string:bar}~is~on~page~\getpagerefnumber{encl\string:bar}

\getencl{encl\string:foo}~is~on~page~\getpagerefnumber{encl\string:foo}

\newpage

%\refstepcounter{encl}
\addencl{Bar}\label{encl:bar}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}

\newpage

\addencl{Foo}\label{encl:foo}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}

%\newwatermark*{}


\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Note: I initially added `\detokenize` to the document commands defined, but there remained a problem with `\getpagerefnumber`.